# Запись стека вызовов при необработанной ошибке

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, исключения

Как записать стек вызовов функций из службы в файл при возникновении необработанной ошибки в Delphi 7?

Comment: А что за служба и как она вызывается, уточните. Проблема в получении стэка или получении стэка из службы? madExcept смотрели?

Comment: В дополнение: чтобы madExcept нормально работал в службе, ему необходимо запретить (снять галочки) показ визуальных сообщений об ошибках, оставить только формирование файла багрепорта.

Comment: Снимаешь все галки в меню exception box  settings и сохраняешь , но одна все равно остается после открытия. может это из-за того что бесплатная версия?

Comment: Вам нужна закладка Exception Filter. Все Комбобоксы со значением `Don't show anything`. Но на этой закладке нельзя отмечать чекбокс `don't create bugreport`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов получения стека вызовов в сервисе.
Самое главное, что нужно понимать - сервисы, начиная с Windows Vista не имеют доступа к рабочему столу пользователя, поэтому они не в состоянии что-либо показывать. Да, в Vista было промежуточное решение (служба обнаружения интерактивных служб) но не стоит на нее ориентироваться.

1. Используем [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net/).

*Способ первый, простой.*

Во-первых, включаем MadExcept и отключаем всё визуальное:

- на вкладке *on exception auto actions* - снимаем галку "show please wait box"
- на вкладке *exception filter* во всех комбобоксах выставляем "don't show anything"

Экспериментируя с созданием багрепортов, изначально у меня не получалось автоматическое создание при возникновении неотловленного исключения. В этом случае может помочь следующий код (не забываем включить в Uses модуль MadExcept):

```pascal
procedure TService3.ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  madExcept.HookThreads;
end;
```

Всё. Теперь MadExcept отслеживает все исключения и тихо создает багрепорты. В зависимости от настроек он так же тихо может отправлять их "куда надо" (не забываем внести создаваемый сервис в исключения файрволла).

*Способ второй* применим для версий Delphi, у которых появилось свойство `Exception.StackTrace`. Ловим исключения самостоятельно. MadExcept не отключаем - он берет на себя генерацию стека вызовов.

```pascal
procedure TService3.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
    try
      ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True);
      raise EInvalidOperation.Create('Error Message x'); // не долго думая, возбуждаем исключение прямо здесь
    except
      on e: Exception do
       // таким образом мы получаем информацию только об исключении,
       // "штатный" для MadExcept способ выдает информации гораздо больше
       // в том числе - о версии приложения, ОС и т.п.
        madExcept.AutoSaveBugReport(e.ToString + #13#10+E.StackTrace);
    end;
end;
```

---

2. Используем [EurekaLog](https://www.eurekalog.com/). Коммерческий продукт, поэтому за подробностями - на их сайт.

---

3. Используем JCL из состава [Jedi](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/).

```pascal
// процедура, отлавливающая исключения и записывающая информацию в файл.
// код честно взят с http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/answer.asp?IDAnswer=57687
procedure ExceptionHook(ExceptObj: TObject; ExceptAddr: Pointer;
  OSException: Boolean);
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Text := 'An exception raised at ' + DateTimeToStr(Now)
      + #13#10 + Exception(ExceptObj).Message + #13#10 + GetLocationInfoStr
      (ExceptAddr, True, True, True, True) + #13#10 + #13#10 +
      'Call stack:'#13#10;
    if JclLastExceptStackList = nil then
      SL.Add('[NOT AVAILABLE]')
    else
      JclLastExceptStackList.AddToStrings(SL, True);
    // StringList использован исключительно для примера.
    // естественно, что в реальности файл багрепорта должен дополняться, а не перезаписываться.
    SL.SaveToFile(ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0), '.log'));
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TService3.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True);
      raise EInvalidOperation.Create('Error Message x'); // не долго думая, возбуждаем исключение прямо здесь
    end;
end;

initialization

JclDebug.JclStackTrackingOptions := [stStack]; // обычный режим
JclAddExceptNotifier(ExceptionHook, npNormal);
JclStartExceptionTracking;
JclTrackExceptionsFromLibraries;

finalization

JclStopExceptionTracking;
```

**Замечание 1** Для работы всех отловщиков исключений необходима отладочная информация. Желательно - созданный map-файл, хотя Jedi дают возможность использовать различные варианты, например - включить отладочную информацию прямо в exe или задействовать отдельные jdbg файлы.

**Замечание 2** Если используется второй способ MadExcept, то все исключения, которые могут возникнуть в таймерах, нужно обрабатывать именно в событии OnTimer, поскольку (по непонятным мне, но наверняка весомым) причинам исключение, возникшее в этом событии, напрямую уходит в метод `HandleException` объекта `Forms.Application`. Переназначить его событие `OnException` на свой обработчик, насколько я понял, нельзя - его уже "забрал" `TServiceApplication`

**Дополнительно:** ссылка для изучения: [gunsmoker.ru](http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2010/04/exception-delphi-2009.html)

Comment: Может не в тему , а где интересно назначаются методы ServiceStart,  ServiceStop обработчикам сервиса FOnStart и FOnStop?  Не могу найти по коду присвоения.

Comment: @gregor в модуле svcmgr смотрите метод `TServiceThread.ProcessRequests`. Назначение идет так же, как и присвоение обработчиков событий для обычных форм - при разборе .dfm файла. А вот вызов - именно в этом методе. Более того, вся работа сервиса ведется именно внутри TServiceThread, т.е. в отдельном потоке, который для сервиса считается главным.